# Why does the `equal` works for const char* in C++?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl, char

The codes are like this, it outputs `1`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector <const char*> vec = {"nima","123"};
    vector <const char*> vec2 = {"nima","123"};
    auto result = equal(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), vec2.cbegin());
    cout << result << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I knew that I can test whether two c-style string is equal only by using `strcmp` (because `char*` is not an object as I understood). But here `equal` is a function from `<algorithm>`. Does it overload the `==` operator so that it can test the equality of two `char*`?

@Damon says that they're equal as the merges the same string literal into same address, as I understood. However, when I tried `char*` with different addresses, it still gives me the same result:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char* k = "123";
char* b = "123";
vector <const char*> vec = {"nima"};
vector <const char*> vec2 = {"nima"};
cout << &k << endl;
cout << &b << endl;
vec.push_back(k);
vec2.push_back(b);

auto result = equal(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), vec2.cbegin());
cout << result << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
 0x7fff5f73b370
 0x7fff5f73b368
 1
```

Comment: [This demo](http://ideone.com/1QyMdO) might make what is going on clearer.

Comment: Concerning your edit, try dynalically allocating the `char` strings and you should get different addresses for each, hence different results.

Comment: @juanchopanza I see, they are the same when I change it to `cout << (int*)k << (int*) b << endl;` Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What probably happens here is that the compiler/linker merges the four string literals of which two are identical into two literals. Therefore, both `"nima"` and both `"123"` have the same address.

You store the addresses in a vector and compare them (`operator==` on an address). Since the addresses are the same, the comparison is equal.

Note that this is **accidential**. It only "works" because of two reasons:

1. The strings are literals (that is, not some strings read from e.g. `stdin`).
2. A compiler is allowed, but not required to merge identical literals (whether or not this happens is implementation-defined).

This can lead to two situations in which you get a funny surprise (not so funny if you must find out why it suddenly doesn't work when it "worked" all the time), either when you use a different compiler or even the same compiler with different optimization settings, or when you assign non-literal strings.

Comment: "Implementation-defined" might be better than "accidental". The relevant standard quote is §2.14.5/12: "Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-defined."

Comment: True, though I also wanted to point out that it _won't work_ when you e.g. add two identical strings that you read from `stdin`. The fact that it "works" in the example (because of an implementation-defined behaviour) can insofar be considered accidential, too. I'll try to reword it less ambiguously.

Comment: I modified the example to make two "123" have different addresss. However, it doesn't change the result..

Comment: @Firegun you are confusing the address of `k` and `b` (different) with the addtess of the string they point to (the same).

Comment: @sftrabbit: you mean `std::cout << (void const*)k << "\n";`, otherwise the content of the c-string is printed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Apologies, I deleted my comment because I noticed that mistake.

Comment: @Firegun I extended [the demo](http://ideone.com/1QyMdO) to show a case where two null terminated strings are identical, yet the comparison of the pointers pointing to the same element yields false.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Alternatively, one could rewrite the example using `argv` ([see here](http://ideone.com/DM1tuJ)). There's no combination of arguments you can give to the program which would possibly result in an equal result (except of course no arguments at all, in which case the elements of `argv` won't be initialized and might (accidentially) all be `NULL`).