# how to give an example to disprove the usage of `==` for comparing `const char*`

Tags: c++

Based on:
[What is the proper function for comparing two C-style strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122000/what-is-the-proper-function-for-comparing-two-c-style-strings)

I know the OP is correct. However, I tried the following with g++ 4.1.2.

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        const char* str1 = "hello worldA";

        if (str1 == "hello worldr")
                std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
        else if ( str1 == "hello worldA" )
                std::cout << "hello worldA " << std::endl;
        else
                std::cout << "not " << std::endl;

        return 0;
}
```

OR

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        const char* str1 = "hello worldA";
        const char* str2 = "hello worldA";

        if (str1 == str2)
                std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
        else
                std::cout << "not " << std::endl;

        return 0;

}
```

The output shows the right comparison result.

Question> How do I design a program so that it shows the `==` doesn't work for `const char*`?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911085/why-does-the-equal-works-for-const-char-in-c

Comment: "*How do I design a program so that it shows the == doesn't work for const char*" -- Simple.  If you know that `const char *` shouldn't be compared, you don't write code to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const char* str1 = "hello worldA";
    char strbuf[] = "hello worldA";

    const char* str2 = strbuf;

    if (str1 == str2)
            std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    else
            std::cout << "not " << std::endl;

    if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
            std::cout << "same contents" << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Output is:

> not
>   same contents

Since one is pointing to a constant and the other is not, there's no way the pointers could be equal. If they were, `*strbuf='Q';` would change the value of `*str1`, and clearly that's wrong.

This is probably an even better way to show it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void compare(const char *str1, const char *str2)
{
    if (str1 == str2)
        std::cout << "== says equal" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "== says uneqal" << std::endl;

    if (strcmp(str2, str1) == 0)
        std::cout << "strcmp says equal" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "strcmp says unequal" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    const char* str1 = "hello worldA";
    char strbuf[] = "hello worldA";

    compare (str1, strbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

Output must be:

> == says uneqal
>   strcmp says equal

Comment: You should explicitly create a `const char*` to point to `str2` so you are comparing two `const char*`s rather than a `const char*` and a `char*`

Comment: Thanks, it's now improved.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
const char* str = "Hello\0Hello";
const char str2 = str+6;
std::cout << str << " =? " << str2 
          << std::boolalpha << " : " << (str == str2);
```

By putting two identical strings adjacent to each other, we know their addresses are unequal.